# How do I embed a NavigationLink inside a block of text in SwiftUI?

Tags: button, text, swiftui

I would like to have a SwiftUI NavigationLink show up inline with a block of Text. How do I do this?

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish. I want the Terms and Conditions to be part of the text and not in a separate view.
[Tap to view image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euqoz.png)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no equivalent of `NSAttributedString` for SwiftUI.

This is probably not what you are looking for, but using stacks might be the best option to achieve your goal (`VStack` or `HStack`, which ever fits better):

```swift
HStack {
    Text("By creating an account, you agree to the")
    Button("Terms & Conditions") {
       // UIApplication.shared.openURL
    }
}
```

You might want to consider localization, since the order of the elements might be different in other languages, possibly including the button being in the middle of the sentence. Not very promising.

I haven't used it, but you might want to look into ways to use `UIViewRepresentable`. With it, you can apply different styles to different parts of the string, but not sure if there is any way to attach event handlers.

Comment: Yeah, I may have to use UIViewRepresentable. It would be nice to do it in SwiftUI though.